# dropdown-menu to take whole width of body - bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make the `horizontal dropdown` menu to take the whole width of the body. The `dropdown-menu` should start from the left in the following fiddle.

[FIDDLE HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/2dmqduy2/)

The `Sub List 1` should start from the `Logo+Text` area and should flow till the `li` continues.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div>
                <span>Logo+Text</span>
            </div>
            <div class="btn-group" style="margin-left: 200px">
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Lists</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Sub List 1</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Sub List 2</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Sub List 3</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Sub List 4</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Sub List 5</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `position: initial;`to the parent class `btn-group`. if not working, then use `!important`.

View my demo on [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/sarowerj/2dmqduy2/6/)

Good practice is: Add a new class  `has_dropdown` to `btn-group`. Then style by `has_dropdown` class. Try as my demo.

Comment: down menu disappears when trying to select menu option

Comment: Please check my jsfiddle link again. I think it's working properly as you made. Dropdown must be hide, when you hover out from them. Because, you made it by css hover method.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to move your `style="margin-left: 200px"` CSS declarations to the `dropdown-toggle` anchor item, instead of the `btn-group`. That way, your container and consequently, your dropdown menu remains aligned to your logo while the trigger gets pushed to the right.